# wordpress forbidden 403 error

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, installation

After installing wordpress and following all the steps when I am go to `http://localhost`, I am gettong `403 Forbidden error`.

How can I resolve this?

Ubuntu 14.04 is my OS.

Comment: Are you installed WordPress in a sub directory? Have you checked the folder permissions? Share the .htaccess file  (you can get it from the WordPress install root).

Comment: I installed it at `/var/www/html`. I am not able to get the .htaccess file.

Comment: Navigate to /var/www/html and press Ctrl + h, then you can see the .htaccess file.

Comment: nothing happening after `Ctrl+h`

Comment: Create .htaccess file inside /var/www/html and add basic htaccess contents - https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: even after that I am getting same error

Comment: Since you are working on local machine, it will be related to permission. open terminal and run 'sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/' - Note: this is just to check whether this is a permission issue, don't use 777 when you move the website to server.

Comment: I already have given this permission. Still the same forbidden error 403

Comment: you need to be more specific with your server info, if you you do not have access to this contact your host

Comment: I am trying it locally. What other information you need?

Answer (score 2):

In normal case changing permission and updating .htaccess should fix this issue, but in your case it is not working, so try to create a host entry and see if it is working. Else it will be related to the server configuration.

a. Create a new folder inside `/var/www` (example: wordpress - with proper permissions)

b. Copy all files from `/var/www/html` folder to `/var/www/wordpress`

c. Create a virtual host entry: `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf`

Add following contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

d. Update hosts: `sudo gedit /etc/hosts`

Add new line: `127.0.1.1    wordpress`

e. Activate new website: `sudo a2ensite wordpress.conf`

d. Restart apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Access http://wordpress from your web browser.

Comment: at the end of the file?

Comment: Yes, try to include this to end of the file.

Comment: did that and refreshed the url. same `403 forbidden issue`

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?  sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: `(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
`

Not able to restart apache either

Comment: That states the issue, Apache2 usually requires port 80. But it is used by other application. Try to change Apache listening port or try to stop the other application or server.

Comment: Also remove the code which you added to: 000-default.conf

Comment: I killed the proccess and tried to restart apache2 again but same above error

Comment: did exact things, but again getting the same forbidden 403 error

Comment: nope, apache2 not restarting. It gives that above error.

Comment: Try this: "fuser -k -n tcp 80" and restart apache.

Comment: just removed apache2 and reinstalling it! Give me a moment please

Comment: Okay, so here was the problem, I think It was because `nginx` was installed and it was not allowing to evem start the apache.

I just removed `nginx` and `apache` restarted well and at `http://wordpress` I am able to render the php code which we have in `index.php` file

Comment: Glad to know buddy :-)

Comment: when I go to `http://ip/wp-admin`

Why I am getting the content of the code instead of the login page?

Comment: Install php and restart apache.

Comment: Create phinfo.php file in your server root and add <?php phpinfo(); ?>. Run that file and see if it works. Else the php installation is not done in the right way (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian-8).

Comment: It is installed properly. I can get that page